# Apache + Ruby in a way like PHP

Tags: ruby, apache2

As you probably know, to do a PHP script, you could just do..

```
<?php
    Code..
?>
```

..and it would run the PHP code, as long as you have the PHP module loaded.

Is there a module that would allow you to do something similar with Ruby? Something like this would be nice:

```
<?ruby
    Code..
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's equivalent would be one of [`Erb`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.9.2/frames), [`Erubis`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/erubis/2.7.0/frames) or [`HAML`](http://haml-lang.com/).

Erb comes with Ruby. Erubis is a compiled interpreter for Erb templates. They use `<%= ... >` to mark where Ruby variables should be inserted. You can also include Ruby control structures easily using `<%- ... >`, to allow looping, creating of variables, etc.

HAML is similar to those, but acts much like a HTML-shorthand. I prefer HAML for my own projects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes modruby would do what you are asking of but you would need to use a template language, ERB would do this for you.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html

But rather than encapsulating <% tags in an .rb file you would use those tags in a template in which those get substituted by values afterwards.

Another safe bet if you want to be a bit more up to date, is to try out sinatra. this is a microframework so it will get you up to a certain level before you move to another framework.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) with [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/)